# figure_factory heatmap figure labels incorrectly applied to integer y-axis values (autotypenumbers not working?)

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I am trying to create a annotated heatmap using plotly figure_factory. All of the y-labels are strings, but some could be interpreted as integers. It seems like the figure automatically interprets some of the axis labels as integers and then reorders the chart values incorrectly. You can see that one of the rows has no labels at all and another row has two labels, one on top of the other.

I tried to apply autotypenumbers="strict" thinking it would help but it has not worked. When I append some character, like "-" to the list of y-labels, the problem is solved because the labels are no longer interpreted as integers. I would prefer to not rely on such a workaround.

Is there a way to apply autotypenumbers to the figure to solve the issue? Is there another solution? (The data below is dummy data - ignore the x and y labels.)

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

z_values = [[1,2,3,4],
            [5,6,7,8],
            [9,10,11,12],
            [13,14,15,16],
            [17,18,19,20],
            [21,22,23,24],]

x_values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

y_values = ['<2', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6<='] y_values.reverse() z_labels = z_values

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
            z=z_values, x=x_values, y=y_values, colorscale='Bluyl', annotation_text=z_labels
        ) fig.update_layout(autotypenumbers="strict") fig.update_xaxes({'type': 'category', 'autotypenumbers': 'strict', 'title': {'text': 'Test label'}}) fig.update_yaxes({'type': 'category', 'autotypenumbers': 'strict', 'title': {'text': 'Test label'}})

fig.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX1cU.png)

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with annotated heatmaps, and the development community says that there is not enough time and resources to improve them. This comment is taken from [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/3172). Also, this issue can be solved by a technique where the y-axis's are created as numerical values and later replaced by the y-axis display string. I referred to [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2782) for the solution method.

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff

z_values = [[1,2,3,4],
            [5,6,7,8],
            [9,10,11,12],
            [13,14,15,16],
            [17,18,19,20],
            [21,22,23,24],]

x_values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

y_values = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
# y_values.reverse()
z_labels = z_values

fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(
            z=z_values, x=x_values, y=y_values, colorscale='Bluyl', annotation_text=z_labels
        )

fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=[0,1,2,3,4,5], ticktext=['<2', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6<='])

fig.show()
```

[image]